# How to fix 'Object(...) is not a function' on ref().set() for Firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to add custom info for a newly created user in Firebase. I'm using ref().set() properly and for some reason it's telling me it's not a function. What am I missing?

I've ensured that I'm using the proper syntax and methods. Everything is defined.

Here is the error in my console:
[Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTq2J.png)

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function 
at writeUserName (db.js:4)
at SignUp.js:54
```

Here is my Firebase config:
[Firebase Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2qG0.png)

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/database';
import 'firebase/auth';

const config = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyDuhQeHZTJOaKdqJhasEKq0jLs4Cv6VZwk",
  authDomain: "yokrapp.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://yokrapp.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "yokrapp",
  storageBucket: "yokrapp.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "303116446076"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

export const firebaseAuth = firebase.auth;
export const database = firebase.database();
export const ref = firebase.database().ref();
```

And here is the code throwing the error:
[ref().set() -> Object(...) is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wijAu.png)

```
import { ref } from '../config';

export const writeUserName = (userId, name) => {
  ref('users/' + userId).set({
    name,
  });
};
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: If you try importing database from the config file instead of ref and using your same code, do you get the same error? Otherwise right now you are effectively doing `firebase.database().ref().ref(someStringPath).set();`

Comment: It works! Thanks!

Comment: Great to hear. I've created an answer with the solution. Please mark if it helped resolve the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try instead importing `database` from your config file with for use with your existing `writeUserName` function:

```
import { database } from '../config';

export const writeUserName = (userId, name) => {
  database.ref('users/' + userId).set({ name });
};
```

As currently with the import of `ref` you effectively doing:

`firebase.database().ref().ref('users/' + userId).set();`

Otherwise you could use [child()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference.html#child) with the `ref` export:

```
import { ref } from '../config';

export const writeUserName = (userId, name) => {
  ref.child('users/' + userId).set({ name });
};
```

Hopefully that helps!